# Jquery select not working as expected

Tags: jquery, selector

I have a table that's rendered dynamically using jQuery after an ajax call.

The table looks correct and has a button in each row.

I have a simple on(click function) that I want to trigger when the button is clicked. The problem I have is that I can't seem to attach the event listener to the button itself.

The row looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>04/01/2013</td>
    <td>LastName, FirstName</td>
    <td>Success looks like this. and other stuff</td>
    <td>
        <button id="serialID1" class="btn btn-small formViewBtn" type="button">View</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

If I use a function like this:

```
$("#tableConversation tbody").on("click", function(){alert('hi mom')});
```

It works.

But, this doesn't and I don't understand why not:

```
$("#tableConversation tbody button").on("click", function(){alert('hi mom')});
```

Neither does this:

```
$("#tableConversation tbody .formViewBtn").on("click", function(){alert('hi mom')});
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dynamically adding content to the table, a "Delegated Event" is probably the best approach here.

```
$("#tableConversation").on("click", "tbody button", function(){alert('hi mom')});
```

For more info, reference the "Delegated Events" section of [jQuery's `on` docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

**Edit - More Info:**

If you use your original method, jQuery will immediately find all the items matching the selector and add a click handler to *each* of them.  But anything added after that call won't have the handler.  If you use the delegated events approach, you can add a single handler "higher up in the DOM", and that handler will deal with all the matching DOM elements regardless of when they get added to the DOM.  The reason this works is that most events rise up the DOM tree until a handler tells the event to stop propagating.  So the jQuery `on` code checks if the target matches and fires the handler.

Comment: that works perfectly, thanks! The concept is still a little squirrely to me. I had found another post that suggested using event.target.getAttribute('type') == 'button', which worked, but your method is more direct. There's something about descendant behavior I'm not quite grasping.

Comment: Oh ok. That explains why it was firing twice when I had attached it to tbody. Many thanks!